# get data in String[] Array using servlet and jsp

Tags: servlets

I am trying to get the values that i inserted in the database dynamically but I can't get the value.
**here my code**

```
         String[] SchoolName = request.getParameterValues("shoolname");
         String[] DateFrom = request.getParameterValues("Dateform");
         String[] DateTo = request.getParameterValues("Datato");
         String[] DiscriptDetails = request.getParameterValues("Dscript");
```

this for insert data and its working well.

```
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < SchoolName.length;++i ) {
            educatiodetails edu = new educatiodetails();
            edu.setSchoolName(SchoolName[i]);
            edu.setDateFrom(DateFrom[i]);
            edu.setDateTo(DateTo[i]);
            edu.setDiscriptDetails(DiscriptDetails[i]);


                     EducatiIMP education = new EducatiIMP();
                     education.addEducation(edu);
                     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);       

                    //here I am trying to get values

                    addEducation.getList();

                   educatiodetails educat =education.geteducatiodetails(SchoolName[i]);  

//here my session just get the first value 

session.setAttribute("educat",educat);
                       }
                      }
```

Comment: How are submitting the data to servlet? are you using ajax or submit the form or anything similar? what is the http method?

Comment: Can you show us the view code as well, at least part of code, where you submit and form fields

Comment: method i use post , the jsp view for view data .    <c:forEach var="educat" items="${educat.schoolName}"> 
                    <h2><c:out value="${educat}"/> </h2>
                </c:forEach>

Comment: can any one help me please ....

Comment: This does not help. Please edit the question and add the view page code. Better consider adding complete jsp code.